# React Refs undefined inside functions and has values outside

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-forwardref

I am having a lot of troubles working with react refs, what i want is to use a function declared in another components

the below code is what i am doing:

```
const Component1 = (props, ref) => {
  const getText = () => {};
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ getText }));
  return <div />;
};
export default React.forwardRef(Component1);

const Component2 = (props) => {
  const component1Ref = React.createRef();
  const getTextFromComponent1 = () => {
    console.log({ component1Ref }); //will be equal to {current:null}
  };
  console.log({ component1Ref }); //will be equal to {current:{getText}}

  return <Component1 ref={component1Ref} />;
};
export default Component2;
```

It is very weird, the value inside getTextFromComponent1 was the same as outside, it suddenly broke! this happened with me many times

Anyone has a clue of the solution?
Features are breaking without any change

Thanks in advance
Hanan

Answer (score 0):

It will take some time for `ref` to be initialized. I have shown an example to call it from a click event handler and within a `useEffect` hook.

Following works without any issues:

```
const Component1 = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const textRef = React.createRef();
  const getText = () => {
    return textRef?.current?.value;
  };
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ getText }));
  return <input ref={textRef} defaultValue="sample text" />;
});

const Component2 = (props) => {
  const component1Ref = React.createRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getTextFromComponent1();
  }, []);

  const getTextFromComponent1 = () => {
    console.log(component1Ref.current?.getText());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={getTextFromComponent1}>Check text</button>
      <br />
      <Component1 ref={component1Ref} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component2;
```

Working Demo

[image: Edit youthful-elbakyan-iwu2r8]

Comment: Thanks for answering! my issue is that current is null inside the function and not null outside of it, it was working and now it stopped! logging both values at the same time shows the difference
So the code is correct! But it stopped working

Comment: Is this the exact structure of your code. Can you add any missing pieces?

Comment: this is the exact structure, i am using an input and taking its value, the issue appears in the second components where i am using the ref.
So the issue is in the ref, it is loosing its value inside a fucntion...

Comment: can you create a code sanbox to recreate the issue and attach it to the question?

Comment: it is not easily reproducible it is happening suddenly, but i will try